# Calculating variance of integrated Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion

Doing an old exam question for one of the courses I'm reading, I was faced with the following problem:

> Let $\left\{B(t); t \geq 0\right\}$ be a Brownian motion, with variance parameter $\sigma^2=1$. Define the process $\left\{X(t); t \geq 0\right\}$ by:
>   $$X(t)=\int_0^t B(u)du, \quad t\geq 0.$$
>   Calculate $P(X(2) > X(1)+1)$.

Obviously, $X(2)-X(1)=\int_1^2 B(u)du$. I do understand why 
$X(2)-X(1)\sim N(0,\tilde{\sigma})$, for some $\tilde{\sigma}$. What I fail to understand is why one could calculate $\tilde{\sigma}$ in this way:

$$\tilde{\sigma}^2= E((X(2)-X(1))^2)=E((\int_1^2 B(u)du)^2){\color{red}=}\int_1^2\int_1^2E(B(t)B(u))dudt=...$$

When calculating $\tilde{\sigma}$ myself, I simply used limits of sums, which worked, though it didn't really feel satisfactory.

What am I failing to see? How did they go from the left-hand side to the right-hand side of the red equality sign above? Could someone do the manipulations in a more step-by-step manner?

Comment: This is an almost sure equality: $$\left(\int_1^2 B(u)du\right)^2=\int_1^2 B(u)du\cdot\int_1^2 B(t)dt=\int_1^2\!\!\!\int_1^2B(t)B(u)dudt$$

Comment: @Did So, $u$ and $t$ here are independent, I guess?

Comment: ?? $u$ and $t$ are integration variables, no independence involved here.

Comment: @Did I didn't mean indepence in random variable sense. Rather in the sense that $B(t)$ can be treated as a constant in the inner integral above. Sometimes I find it hard to keep terminology apart.